# What are the conditions for this sum to converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to figure out the conditions for 
$$\sum_k^{\infty} (N+k)a^{2k}{}_2F_1\left(1-k,1-N-k;2;\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2\right)$$
converging, where $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $\{a,b\}\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is the Gaussian hypergeometric function.

Thanks to @gammatester, the Hypergeometric function reduces to a polynomial, so the sum can be written as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (N+k)a^{2k} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}(-1)^n\binom{k-1}{n}\frac{(1-N-k)_n}{(2)_n}\left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^{2n},$$

where the Pochhammer symbol $(x)_n$ has been used.

---

Looking for a moment only at the exponential factors and considering only the biggest value of $n$ $(n=k-1)$, we have something that scales as $$a^{2k}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2(k-1)}=a^2b^{2k-2},$$

so I think $b<1$ is required. But from doing numerical analysis in Mathematica, I found $a<1$ and $a+b\leq 1$ also seems to be necessities.

**Is this true? If yes, why? And are there any other constraints for the sum to converge?**

Thanks.

Comment: Note that, if $a$ or $b$ in ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ are non-positive integers (as it is in your case) the hypergeometric function actually is a polynom so that there is **no** convergence problem and no restriction $|z|<1$ for ${}_2F_1$ itself.

Comment: @gammatester So $a\geq b$ (in the sum) is not necessary is what you're saying?

Comment: No, you only cannot exclude it a-priori.

Comment: @gammatester Yeah, that was what I meant (that it wasn't a necessary condition for the convergence) - thanks! :) You say it reduces to a polynomial; do you have a resource where I might have a look at such a transformation?

Comment: See e.g. http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2. Simply because the Pochhammer symbols in the numerators $(a)_s$ or $(b)_s$ become zero. (15.2.4) explicitely mentioned that it becomes a polynomial. In http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8#ii you find transformations for these cases.

Comment: @gammatester Thanks. In (15.2.4), how would you interpret $(b)_n$ when $b\in \mathbb{Z}^{-}$? Is the formula still valid then?

Comment: There is no special treatment if $b$ is a negative integer: $(b)_0=1$ and $(b)_n = b(b+1)(b+2)\cdots (b+n-1)$

Comment: @gammatester Of course, thanks again!